# Understanding batch size in neural networks

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying to understand batch size parameter in neural networks (present in keras, tensorflow and etc). Here is my understanding how neural network works. Assume we have independent vector $x = (x_1, ..., x_n )$ and dependent vector $y = (y_1, ... y_n)$. We would like to find a function s.t.:
$$f(w, x_i)= y_i.$$ 
We do so by trying to find minimum (using gradient decent with absolute value loss function) of the following function

$$\|f(w, x_1) - y_1\|= g_1(w), $$
with respect of $w$ at some initial point $w_1$. 
Next step is to minimize

$$\|f(w, x_2) - y_2\|= g_2(w), $$
with respect of $w$ at some initial point $w_2=w_1+\Delta$.

Now processing each coordinate makes sense, but what are the benefit of batch processing? Assume that we would like to process $x_1$ and $x_2$ at once. Are we going to do it at some initial point $w_1$, if so, we end up with $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$. Do we apply these deltas consecutively to $w_1$ or do we average them off? What am I missing? I am guessing that batch processing has something to do with programming implementation, but it does link back to above math?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In batch processing, the gradient is evaluated for several different input/output values, with each observation yielding a different vector. We then average together the gradient vectors over all observations in the batch and take a single step in the resulting direction.

The benefit of this is that the gradient estimate using a single point only may be very noisy. By averaging together the gradient over many samples we obtain a less noisy estimate.

I'll also point out that having too large of a batch can also be a bad thing. Sometimes the noise in the gradient direction can kick you out of local minima and help you get to a better solution. This is problem specific, though, so when training a NN, you should experiment with many different batch sizes. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5533) goes into further detail about this.